# Not able to scroll my Linear Layout using ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

This is my XML file for presenting the Layout.

**edit_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_userregisteration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <com.shout.networking.view.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_placeholder"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/camera"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="What do we call you"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_reg_Fname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:hint="first name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#7c7875" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_reg_Lname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:hint="last name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#7c7875" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_male"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_radio_button"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:text="Male"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_female"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="false"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_radio_button"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:text="Female"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="School of your cool"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_university"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:hint="add your university"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#7c7875" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="what you call home"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_livingaddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:hint="Where do you live now"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColorHint="#7c7875" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_permanentaddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:hint="Where do you belong to"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#7c7875" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Whats Your Calling"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_interset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sp_interset"
                android:hint="Type in your calling/pick from the list"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#7c7875"
                android:maxLines="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_interset"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/down_thicker"
                android:dropDownWidth="250dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:popupBackground="#4b4b49"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_signup_button"
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_signup_button"
                android:text="SAVE"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the screenshot for my Layout.I am not able to scroll it.

[image: screenshot]

I have put my Linear LAyout in the ScrollView but then also i am unable to get the scroll functionality in my xml design .

Comment: try  android:fillViewport="true"  on the ScrolView
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

Comment: Add  `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `ScrolView`  and remove         `android:isScrollContainer="true"` from `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Use this android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrolView

Comment: No neither of them is working.It is distorting my layout items

Comment: Then use custom nested scrollview also remove   _android:gravity="center"_ from _LinearLayout_

Comment: I did not got any positive response

Comment: Replace  `android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"` with `android:paddingLeft="25dp" android:paddingRight="25dp" android:paddingTop="30dp"` @SamarthKejriwal

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Solved ur issue?

Comment: @Piyush Actually i shifted my layout a bit above to get rid of scrolling .I will see to this issue afterwards .If u get some other solution ,then please tell me .Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

make changes in LinearLayout height to match_parent. it will work.

Comment: Child view of `ScrollView` always contains height as a _wrap_content_

Comment: @AKASHWANGALWAR yes i tried the match parent .It did'nt worked

Answer (score 0):

In `ScrollView` try adding this line:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`